How can I prevent gpg-agent from asking for a password?
I am using Fedora 40 (KDE) and I have followed the Arch Wiki guide on how to set it up. However, I would like to unlock - or, whatever is happening in the background - my GPG keys upon login. I am trying to set it up in a similar fashion to how ssh-agent works: that it caches the password (?) and it doesn't ask for it when you SSH into a remote machine; it just logs you straight in.
The way it works now, is that it caches the password for however long you have set up default-cache-* but if you log out and back in, you'll have to reenter the passphrase.
